# How to change graph colour above and below plotline in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

In HighCharts Line Chart, how do I set the colour of a series line depending on its value in relation to the value of a plotline.

For example, if I have a plotline `y = 15`, how could I make the series colour green when `y < 15` and red when `y > 15`

http://jsfiddle.net/adamtsiopani/YBMny/

```
$('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {


    rangeSelector: {
        selected: 1
    },

    title: {
        text: 'KPN Year View'
    },

    yAxis: {
        plotLines: [{ 
            label: {
                text: 'Baseline',
                x: 25
            },
            color: 'orange',
            width: 2,
            value: 15,
            dashStyle: 'longdashdot'
        }],
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'KPN12345',
        data: [
            [1327881600000, 11],
            [1327968000000, 18],
            [1328054400000, 12],
            [1328140800000, 5],
            [1328227200000, 11],
            [1328486400000, 17],
            [1328572800000, 10],
            [1328659200000, 10],
            [1328745600000, 15],
            [1328832000000, 10],
            [1329091200000, 11]
        ]
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can do this with a combination of the [threshold](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.line.threshold) and [negativeColor](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.negativeColor) series options.

```
      series: [{
        name: 'KPN12345',
        data: [
            [1327881600000, 11],
            etc...
        ],
        threshold: 15,
        negativeColor: 'green',
        color: 'red',
        tooltip: {
            valueDecimals: 2
        }
    }]
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/YBMny/3/).

[image]

Comment: is it also possible to change the color of the text in the tooltip based on this value?

Comment: @Adamski: to do that you'd probably have to add a custom tooltip formatter.  See example: http://jsfiddle.net/YBMny/7/

Comment: You should consider using "#00FF00" and "#FF0000" instead of "red" and "green". If using color codes, highcharts will modify the color to apply default stylings, such as the opacity fade in the navigator of a StockChart, that it won't do with just "red".